# 'KeyPressFcn' function to return a value

Tags: matlab, input, figure

I'm trying to find a way for the function I designate as my 'KeyPressFcn' to return a value.

Currently I have:

```
figure('KeyPressFcn', @myFunc);
```

Which is fine, but I need access to the value myFunc returns

Is there a way to do this?

I've been over at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html#KeyPressFcn but looking at the examples they show, I still don't get whats going on.

The example they use has:

```
figure('KeyPressFcn', @(obj,evt)disp(evt));
```

And it says it says the function is passed an event struct. So why isn't it simply:

```
figure('KeyPressFcn', @disp(evt));
```

What is the significance of the (obj,evt) terms in front of the function name?

What is evt? what is obj? what is the significance of

Comment: I think the fastest (and ugliest) way would probably be to store the value in a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a value with callback functions in MATLAB. Instead, you can use functions like [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html). You can get the data you have set with [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) when you need it.

You can use them like this:

```
function myFunc(obj, evt)
    a = 42;
    setappdata(0, 'varName', a);
end
```

Outside of the callback:

```
otherVarName = getappdata(0, 'varName');
```

`otherVarName` will have the value of 42.

---

`obj` is the object whose callback is executing. `evt` is eventdata. [GUIDE documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/customizing-callbacks-in-guide.html) says this:

> hObject — Handle of the object, e.g., the GUI component, for which the
>   callback was triggered. For a button group SelectionChangeFcn
>   callback, hObject is the handle of the selected radio button or toggle
>   button.
>
> eventdata — Sequences of events triggered by user actions such
>   as table selections emitted by a component in the form of a MATLAB
>   struct (or an empty matrix for components that do not generate
>   eventdata)

Here, `hObject` is `obj` and `eventdata` is `evt`.

Let's say you have an editbox and you want to get the text the user has written. For that, you need the handle of the editbox. That's what `hObject` gives you.

```
function buttonCallback(hObject, eventdata)
    str = get(hObject, 'String');
end
```